# Faster alternative of forward/backward model selection for big datasets

Tags: r, predictive-models, model-selection, forward-backward

I want to perform a forward/backward selection to build a predictive model. My data set is very large though and if I include all variables in the selection process it is way too slow. Therefore I am searching for alternative ways how I could choose the variables in an automated way. One idea is to split the data into several data sets and run a forward/backward selection in each data set separately. In a second step I could take all variables, which have been chosen in the split selections and run a final selection with these variables. However, I am not sure, if - from a theoretical viewpoint - this is a proper procedure. Could I chose my variables like that? Are there better ways to chose variables in an automated way based on a large data set? Thank you very much in advance!

Reproducible example:

```
library("MASS")

# Example data
N <- 10000
y <- rnorm(N, 0, 5)
x_uncorrelated <- rnorm(N * 100, 0, 100)
x_correlated <- y + rnorm(N * 10, 0, 100)
data <- data.frame(y, 
               matrix(x_uncorrelated, ncol = 100), 
               matrix(x_correlated, ncol = 10))

# Estimation of model with all variables
mod_all <- lm(y ~ ., data)
summary(mod_all)

# Stepwise variable selection (both directions) with all variables
# Too slow; R breaks down
#step <- stepAIC(mod_all, direction = "both")

# --> Split dataframe and run stepAIC several times

# Split data in groups for forward/backward model selection
step_group <- sample(1:5, ncol(data), replace = TRUE)

data_group_1 <- data[ , step_group == 1]
data_group_2 <- data[ , step_group == 2]
data_group_3 <- data[ , step_group == 3]
data_group_4 <- data[ , step_group == 4]
data_group_5 <- data[ , step_group == 5]

# Add target variable to each dataset
data_group_1$y <- data$y
data_group_2$y <- data$y
data_group_3$y <- data$y
data_group_4$y <- data$y
data_group_5$y <- data$y

# Estimation of model with group variables
mod_group_1 <- lm(y ~ ., data_group_1)
mod_group_2 <- lm(y ~ ., data_group_2)
mod_group_3 <- lm(y ~ ., data_group_3)
mod_group_4 <- lm(y ~ ., data_group_4)
mod_group_5 <- lm(y ~ ., data_group_5)

# Stepwise variable selection (both directions)
step_group_1 <- stepAIC(mod_group_1, direction = "both")
step_group_2 <- stepAIC(mod_group_2, direction = "both")
step_group_3 <- stepAIC(mod_group_3, direction = "both")
step_group_4 <- stepAIC(mod_group_4, direction = "both")
step_group_5 <- stepAIC(mod_group_5, direction = "both")

# Data with all remaining variables
data_step_all <- data[ , colnames(data) %in% c(colnames(step_group_1$model),
                                                        colnames(step_group_2$model),
                                                        colnames(step_group_3$model),
                                                        colnames(step_group_4$model),
                                                        colnames(step_group_5$model))]
dim(data_step_all)

# Estimation of model with group variables
mod_all <- lm(y ~ ., data_step_all)
summary(mod_all)

# Stepwise variable selection (both directions) with all remaining variables
step_all <- stepAIC(mod_all, direction = "both")

# Data with selected variables
data_step_all <- data[ , colnames(data) %in% colnames(step_all$model)]
dim(data_step_all)

# Estimation of model with selected variables
mod_all <- lm(y ~ ., data_step_all)
summary(mod_all)
```

Comment: I would not recommend using forward-backward selection to begin with - is there any reason you are not using Ridge Regression or Lasso or Elastic Nets?

Comment: Forward-backward selection is the standard procedure in the company I am working for. Therefore, it would be harder to sell another method. However, I know that forward-backward selection has been criticized a lot and if there are other methods, which work better for large data sets I would definitely consider them. Which of those methods would you recommend for large data sets?

Comment: Use glmnet and check out the glmnet function. It can do Lasso, Ridge, or any combination between the two (=Elastic Nets). You can find plenty of online resources about those three techniques.

Comment: Its worth mentioning that glmnet is prefferable for all datasets, not just large ones.

Comment: Thank you for the additional feedback @ Metthew. I will definitely have a look